# Gatsby: Best way to handle mouse event listener on dropdown

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, warnings, gatsby

I'm currently building a website with Gatsby and adding a 'hover' dropdown for my navigation. My code is working exactly the way I want, but I am not sure how to change/handle the warnings I keep getting:

```
'warning  Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners'
```

Below is the mark up for my navigation:

```js
<div 
  className={ isProductActive ? "btn active" : "btn"}
  onMouseEnter={ () => this.setState({isProductDDActive: true}) }
  onMouseLeave={ () => this.setState({isProductDDActive: false}) }
  role="link" 
  tabIndex={0}
>
  Header Link
</div>
<ul 
  className={ isProductActive ? "dropdown active" : "dropdown"}
  onMouseEnter={ () => this.setState({isProductDDActive: true}) }
  onMouseLeave={ () => this.setState({isProductDDActive: false}) }
>
  <li>
    <Link to="/">
      Dropdown Link 1
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/">
      Dropdown Link 2
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/">
      Dropdown Link 3
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's an ESlint warning.
The warning means, that you should not have onMouseLeave, onMouseEnter or other event listener on ul / li (no-interactive) elements, only on elements like <a> or <button>.

Comment: Thanks @andybeli - I did research this and found that same answer as you gave. But I don't really want to code my dropdown with <a> or <button>'s. For example, Square does the same thing (check their header navigation) - https://squareup.com/us/en - and they have their mark up with <ul> <li>. Would they be just ignoring their warnings for this?

Comment: that's because you don't really need to handle state and events to achieve this functionality. You could just do it with css.